# Ping IP works, but no TCP/UDP

Tags: router, dns, ping, tcp

I have a new router and it's problematic to connect to the Internet through it. I am unable to download, ping or make a `nslookup` of example.com:

```
$ curl -vvv example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: example.com/
* Could not resolve host: example.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com
$ ping example.com
ping: unknown host example.com
$ traceroute example.com
example.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `example.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
$ nslookup example.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I have an IP address though:

```
$ ifconfig
[...]
wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [snip] 
      inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: [snip]/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7827 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7854 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4282672 (4.2 MB)  TX bytes:1272800 (1.2 MB)
```

My routing table:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

I can access router's web interface (192.168.0.1) from the browser.
I can also ping external IPs, for example `example.com` == `93.184.216.34`:

```
$ ping 93.184.216.34
PING 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=117 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=115 ms
^C
--- 93.184.216.34 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 115.365/116.258/117.151/0.893 ms
```

Downloading it doesn't work though, even when using IP instead of name:

```
$ curl -vvv 93.184.216.34
* Rebuilt URL to: 93.184.216.34/
*   Trying 93.184.216.34...
^C
```

Since DNS is a protocol using UDP, and I can't resolve addresses, nor can I connect to IPs directly, I would guess I have no UDP or TCP connection, but for some reason ping probes pass through the router. What could be misconfigured in this case? Note that I tried using other device (my smartphone) to connect to the router's wifi, and it cannot connect to the Internet either.

Comment: I don't know why, but I feel the last error is a red herring. Check your DNS settings, as everything else points to those being broken.

Comment: http://93.184.216.34 -> 404. Why do you expect curl to work on a broken website?

Comment: Timeout != 404.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. I pinged example.com from another computer and this was the IP that showed up. Anyway, I tried `curl`ing another, working IP, and the result was the same.

Comment: About DNS settings: the router has 8.8.8.8 set as "preferred DNS", and the local settings shouldn't really matter, since I didn't set anything special on my laptop and the Internet 'just works' when connecting to other Wifis.

Comment: Your last comment is wrong. The system will resolve DNS queries based on its configuration. Try `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and ping those addresses

Comment: The resolv.conf contains, apart from resolvconf(8) comments, only `nameserver 127.0.1.1`. Pinging it of course works, but I doubt it's useful.

Comment: Anyway, if I'm not mistaken, I should be able to download pages by IP or connect to them through netcat - only the translation of URLs to IPs should be down, right?

Comment: Try setting DNS on your laptop explicitly, maybe router doesn't have local DNS, or it doesn't work properly.